# How do I apply a style to all cross-references in a document?

Tags: vba, ms-word, hyperlink, cross-reference

I created a hyperlink style that turns text blue and bold.

I would like to apply the style to the hyperlinks in the document.

When I run the macro the output is "no hyperlinks found."

```vb
    Dim objDoc As Document
    Dim objFld As Field

    Set objDoc = ActiveDocument 
    If Selection.Fields.Count >= 1 Then
        For Each objFld In objDoc.Fields 
            If objFld.Type = wdFieldRef Then 
                objFld.ShowCodes = True
                objFld.Select
                Selection.Collapse wdCollapseStart
                Selection.MoveStartUntil "R"
                Selection.Fields(1).Code.Text = Selection.Fields(1).Code.Text & "\*CharFormat"
                Selection.Style = ActiveDocument.Styles("HyperlinkStyle")
                objFld.Update 
                objFld.ShowCodes = True
            End If
        Next objFld
    Else
        MsgBox "No hyperlinks found.", vbInformation, "Select OK"
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Record a macro that looks for the 'Hyperlink' style and replaces it with your Preferred style.  This can be done using the standard find and replace dialog.

Comment: Try to change in the if statement Selection to objDoc.

Answer (score 1):

Although your cross references link to other parts of the document they are not treated the same as actual hyperlinks. If they were the default Hyperlink and FollowedHyperlink styles would be applied.

You are seeing that message, the wording of which is misleading, not because there are no hyperlinks in the document, but because there are no fields in the currently selected text. You can avoid this by looking at the document as a whole rather than just the selected text.

Personally, I would rename "HyperlinkStyle" to "Cross Reference Text" to make the purpose of the style clear, unless you intend all hyperlinks to be formatted that way in which case just modify the Hyperlink style and use that.

You can also avoid changing the selection at all by working directly with `objFld`:

Sub FormatCrossReferences()
Dim objDoc As Document
Dim objFld As Field

```
Set objDoc = ActiveDocument
If objDoc.Fields.Count >= 1 Then
    For Each objFld In objDoc.Fields
        With objFld
            If .Type = wdFieldRef Then
                If Not Right(.Code.Text, 13) = "\*CharFormat " Then .Code.Text = .Code.Text & "\*CharFormat "
                .Code.Characters.First.Style = objDoc.Styles("Cross Reference Text")
                .Result.Style = objDoc.Styles("Cross Reference Text")
            End If
        End With
    Next objFld
Else
    MsgBox "No cross references found.", vbInformation, "Select OK"
End If
```

End Sub

Comment: Thank you so much, this worked! Although when I refresh the links, the style disappears and reverts back to the style that it was previously/same as the surrounding text. For example, if I had a cross-reference that was in a normal style, then when I apply the macro, it picks up my Cross Reference Text character style, but then if I refresh it reverts back to normal. Is there a way around it? Thanks again

Comment: @CG - see updated code above. For the formatting to remain following updates it is necessary to also apply the style to the first character of the field code.

Comment: One last thing, is it possible to tell it to ignore the Table of Contents? It restyles the hyperlinks there. Thanks